# getting properties from table fails if I join the same table twice

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to combine data from two tables but running into issues because of the odd way the contacts table is formatted. When I run my query it returns no results, Why cant I get both phone and email? If I try to get them separately it works perfectly.

I have a Users table:

```
id Name   email
1  Bill   abc@gmail.com
```

And a Contacts table:

```
id Name Data
1  phone 1234
1  email abc@gmail.com
```

My MSSQL query:

```
select co.Data as phone, 
co2.Data as Email 
from Users u 
left join Contacts co on c.id=u.id 
left join Contacts co2 on c2.id=u.id 
where co.Name='email' 
and co2.Name='phone'   --if i dont add this emails and ebverything show up
```

Comment: It might be worth looking into creating a pivot table view off your contacts table to make things like this much easier.

Comment: the aliases don't match in a few places... are those just typos?

Comment: @Greenspark yep those were typos. I think I fixed them all, but if you see anymore please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more predicates to your join. I agree that the table is not a great architecture. It is an EAV style which is a pain to work with.

```
select c.Data as phone
    , co2.Data as Email 
from Users u 
left join Contacts c on c.id = u.id
    AND co.Name = 'email' 
left join Contacts co2 on c2.id = u.id 
    AND and co2.Name='phone'
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but I end up with rows that have NULL email and phone values (for the same person) possibly due to the left join. Is there another join I could use to get rid of the NULL's?

Comment: I'm presuming it's possible for a person to have an email but no phone number, or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, however in the case im working on I have confirmed that everyone has both an email and a phone number

Comment: You could use an inner join but if either the phone or email is missing the entire row will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not reproducible.   I ran this script:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (
  id tinyint
  );

INSERT INTO @Users (id) VALUES (1);

DECLARE @Contacts TABLE (
  id tinyint
, [Name] varchar(31)
, [Data] varchar(31)
); 

INSERT INTO @Contacts (id, Name, Data) VALUES (1,'Phone','1234'),(1,'email','abc@gmail.com');

select co.Data as phone, 
co2.Data as Email 
from @Users u 
left join @Contacts co on co.id=u.id 
left join @Contacts co2 on co2.id=u.id 
where co.Name='phone' 
and co2.Name='email'
```

And got:

```
phone   Email
1234    abc@gmail.com
```

So you had some typo or something else that you left of out your post causing your query not to work.

For instance, I corrected your aliases to use `co` and `co2` throughout.   There are places in your query where you used `c` and `c2`.

Also I corrected the where clause to associate `co` with "phone" and `co2` with "email", since that's how they are associated in the SELECT list.   You have them backwards in the query in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view pivoting your contacts data which will make many other uses of your contacts data much simpler.

```
CREATE VIEW vContactsPivoted
AS
SELECT
    id, email, phone
FROM
    Contacts
    PIVOT (MAX(data) FOR [name] IN (email, phone)) pivoted
```

After that you can use simple joins like any other traditional table:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.[Name],
    c.phone,
    c.email
FROM
    [Users] u
    JOIN vContactsPivoted c ON u.id = p.id
```